# How to invoke a controller action from a path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Is there a way to invoke programmatically an action of a controller?

For example, something like:

```
var controller = new MyWebApiController();
controller.InvokeAction("/myAction?param1=2");
```

I know I can use directly "controller.MyAction(2)" but I have the path and query in a string and I want to map directly to the function and parameters.

Environment: ASP NET CORE 2.0

*Update:*

I am not invoking it from another controller. I need to invoke it from a regular function triggered by an external event. The data received is the path and query, like "/myAction?param1=2"

Comment: If you are invoking this from another controller there are many ways https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910948/can-we-call-the-method-of-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-asp-net-mvc.

Comment: Thank you. I saw the answer but most of them call directly the action from the code. I have the path and query in a string. By the way, I am not invoking it from a controller. It is from a function triggered by external events.

Answer (score 2):

You can call it from controller by splitting the string in parts like this

```
string urlPath = "/myAction?param1=2";
string[] str = urlPath.Split(new[] { "/", "?", "=" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var actionName = str[0];
var parameterVal = str[2];
return RedirectToAction(actionName, CONTROLLERNAME, new { parameterVal });
```